# Qt.inputMethod.show () doesn't show any keyboard

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Considering "Property and Method Changes" from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html):

> TextInput and TextEdit's openSoftwareInputPanel() and closeSoftwareInputPanel() methods have been removed. Use the new Qt.inputMethod property and call Qt.inputMethod.show() Qt.inputMethod.hide() to show and hide the virtual keyboard.

I've written the simple example below.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    id:         root
    visible:    true
    width:      600
    height:     557

    Rectangle
    {
        id:           numberInputBox
        height:       500
        width:        300
        border.color: "green"

        TextInput
        {
            id:             textInput
            font.pixelSize: 20
            cursorVisible:  true
            height: 500
            width: 300

            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked:
                {
                    Qt.inputMethod.show()
                    console.log("getPrinted")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas the text from `console.log` gets printed, I cannot see any keyboard on screen.

---

UPDATE:

I tried:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    id:         root
    visible:    true
    width:      600
    height:     557

    Rectangle
    {
        id:           numberInputBox
        height:       500
        width:        300
        border.color: "green"
        property string numericText

        TextInput
        {
             id:             textInput
             text:           parent.numericText
             focus:          true
             activeFocusOnPress: true
             font.pixelSize: 20
             cursorVisible:  false

             MouseArea
             {
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 onClicked:
                 {
                     Qt.inputMethod.show ()
                     console.log("fsdfsdf")
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the text gets printed but the keypad doesn't get shown.
**I am on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with Qt 5.4 and QtCreator 3.3.0**

Comment: Where did are you porting the code? The example provided works perfectly fine (without `MouseArea`) in Android and iOS. On other platform I think you can exploit the `onFocusChanged` handler, given that [`activeFocusOnPress` is by default to true](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#activeFocusOnPress-prop).

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Not helpful. I tried what you said, but the keypad wasn't shown. I am on `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ` with `Qt 5.4` and `QtCreator 3.3.0`.

Comment: AFAIK the virtual keyboard for desktop is not available in the community edition. If you are on desktop no virtual keyboard is shown.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo So, on what device should I test it on? what is the "community edition"? Thanks.

Comment: [Here is the virtual keyboard](http://doc.qt.io/QtVirtualKeyboard/). which is available under commercial license by Digia. "Community edition" is GPL/LGPL version of Qt. Some components (such as virtual keyboard) is only available in commercial versions. You can test the code with a mobile device, Android or iOS. In these environments Qt hook up to the native system and calls the native virtual keyboard.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Thanks for the info. You can probably write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the [`Qt Virtual Keyboard`](http://doc.qt.io/QtVirtualKeyboard/) is only available in top level licensed version of Qt, i.e. the "professional" and "enterprise" ones, as clearly demonstrated by the feature table available at [this download page](http://www.qt.io/download/).

"Community edition" (the open source version of Qt) does not include the keyboard. Hence, on desktop systems, physical keyboard is the only available input option. Differently, in mobile platforms, Qt hooks up the native virtual keyboard system by default and there is no need to call `Qt.inputMethod`. Given that, the example in the question can be simply rephrased as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    id:         root
    visible:    true
    width:      600
    height:     557

    Rectangle
    {
        id:           numberInputBox
        height:       500
        width:        300
        border.color: "green"
        property string numericText

        TextInput
        {
             id:             textInput
             text:           parent.numericText
             focus:          true
             activeFocusOnPress: true
             font.pixelSize: 20
             cursorVisible:  false  
        }
    }
}
```

Executing this example on a WinPhone, Android or iOS device will correctly show the native virtual keyboard as soon as the `TextInput` is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because you need to give the `TextInput` focus:

```
focus: true
```

This works for me on Desktop, where the only way I know of to test this is to use [Qt's Virtual Keyboard](http://doc.qt.io/QtVirtualKeyboard/) (and set `QT_IM_MODULE=qtvirtualkeyboard` before running the application), as BaCaRoZzo already mentioned. On platforms with native virtual keyboards, such as Android, the explicit call to `Qt.inputMethod.show()` isn't necessary.

Comment: Not helpful. I tried what you said, but the keypad wasn't shown. I am on `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ` with `Qt 5.4` and `QtCreator 3.3.0`.

Comment: Right, that's because I forgot to mention that I was using the virtual keyboard that BaCaRoZzo mentioned in the comments under your question. Again, as they mentioned, on platforms like Android and iOS, the explicit call to Qt.inputMethod.show() isn't necessary, as the TextInput already opens the native keyboard.